Trying to capture 8080 Bus using STM32 Approach
Following with that great answer
Reverse engineer LCD Protocol used in MPC2000XL
I'm trying to capture the data using stm32, it appears that I need to use DMA with Parallel Input.
I have setup Timer2 channel 1 with trigger on IOWRD(PA0), and wanted to start a dma transfer. I can capture the IOWR falling edge signal using the following code, but DMA never starts.
I'm trying to copy the GPIOD to memory, then I can process that buffer.
Here is the configuration:
void TIM2_IRQHandler(void) {
    HAL_TIM_IRQHandler(&htim2);
    HAL_DMA_Start_IT(htim2.hdma[TIM_DMA_ID_CC1], (uint32_t)&(GPIOD->IDR), (uint32_t)buffer, DMA_BUFFER_SIZE);

}
void HAL_DMA_XferCpltCallback(DMA_HandleTypeDef *hdma)
{
    if (hdma->Instance == DMA2_Stream2)
    {
        // DMA transfer complete callback code here
    }
}
// DMA interrupt handler
void DMA2_Stream2_IRQHandler(void) {
    HAL_DMA_IRQHandler(htim2.hdma[TIM_DMA_ID_CC1]);
}
void XferCpltCallback(DMA_HandleTypeDef *hdma)
{
    if (hdma->Instance == DMA1_Stream5) {
        uint8_t A1;
        uint8_t CS1;
        uint8_t CS2;
        uint8_t data_byte = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            data_byte |= ((buffer[0] >> i) & 0x01) << i;
        }
        A1  = (buffer[0] >> 8) & 0x01;
        CS1 = (buffer[0] >> 9) & 0x01;
        CS2 = (buffer[0] >> 10) & 0x01;
        if ((!CS1) && (!A1)) {
            LCD1_write_cmd(data_byte);
        }
        if ((!CS1) && (A1)) {
            LCD1_write_dat(data_byte);
        }
        if ((!CS2) && (!A1)) {
            LCD2_write_cmd(data_byte);
        }
        if ((!CS2) && (A1)) {
            LCD2_write_dat(data_byte);
        }

    }
}
static void MX_TIM2_Init(void)
{

     GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct = {0};

      TIM_ClockConfigTypeDef sClockSourceConfig;
      TIM_MasterConfigTypeDef sMasterConfig;
      TIM_IC_InitTypeDef sConfigIC;

      /* Peripheral clock enable */
      __TIM2_CLK_ENABLE();

      /* Peripheral interrupt init*/
      HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(TIM2_IRQn, 0, 0);
      HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(TIM2_IRQn);

      /**TIM2 GPIO Configuration
      PA0/WKUP     ------> TIM2_CH1
      */
      GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_0;
      GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_AF_PP;
      GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
      GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_LOW;
      GPIO_InitStruct.Alternate = GPIO_AF1_TIM2;
      HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStruct);

      htim2.Instance = TIM2;
      htim2.Init.Prescaler = 0;
      htim2.Init.CounterMode = TIM_COUNTERMODE_UP;
      htim2.Init.Period = 0xFFFFFFFF;
      htim2.Init.ClockDivision = TIM_CLOCKDIVISION_DIV1;
      HAL_TIM_Base_Init(&htim2);

      sClockSourceConfig.ClockSource = TIM_CLOCKSOURCE_INTERNAL;
      HAL_TIM_ConfigClockSource(&htim2, &sClockSourceConfig);

      HAL_TIM_IC_Init(&htim2);

      sMasterConfig.MasterOutputTrigger = TIM_TRGO_RESET;
      sMasterConfig.MasterSlaveMode = TIM_MASTERSLAVEMODE_DISABLE;
      HAL_TIMEx_MasterConfigSynchronization(&htim2, &sMasterConfig);

      /* Input capture stuff HERE
         Change polarity as needed */
      sConfigIC.ICPolarity = TIM_INPUTCHANNELPOLARITY_FALLING;
      sConfigIC.ICSelection = TIM_ICSELECTION_DIRECTTI;
      sConfigIC.ICPrescaler = TIM_ICPSC_DIV1;
      sConfigIC.ICFilter = 0;
      HAL_TIM_IC_ConfigChannel(&htim2, &sConfigIC, TIM_CHANNEL_1);



}

static void MX_DMA_Init(void)
{
    __HAL_RCC_DMA2_CLK_ENABLE();


    // DMA initialization code here

    hdma_tim2_ch1.Instance = DMA2_Stream2;

    hdma_tim2_ch1.Init.Channel = DMA_CHANNEL_6;

    hdma_tim2_ch1.Init.Direction = DMA_MEMORY_TO_MEMORY;

    hdma_tim2_ch1.Init.PeriphInc = DMA_PINC_DISABLE;
    hdma_tim2_ch1.Init.MemInc = DMA_MINC_ENABLE;
    hdma_tim2_ch1.Init.PeriphDataAlignment = DMA_PDATAALIGN_BYTE ; /* only reading in GPIO PB[15:8]... PB[7:0] used on FSMC */
    hdma_tim2_ch1.Init.MemDataAlignment = DMA_MDATAALIGN_WORD ;
    hdma_tim2_ch1.Init.Mode = DMA_NORMAL;  /* double memory buffer used */
    hdma_tim2_ch1.Init.Priority = DMA_PRIORITY_HIGH;
    hdma_tim2_ch1.Init.FIFOMode = DMA_FIFOMODE_DISABLE; /* using FIFO mode since memory datasize=32bit and GPIO=8bits in our case */

    __HAL_LINKDMA(&htim2, hdma[TIM_DMA_ID_CC1], hdma_tim2_ch1);

    if (HAL_DMA_Init(htim2.hdma[TIM_DMA_ID_CC1]) != HAL_OK)

    {

        Error_Handler();

    }

    HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(DMA2_Stream2_IRQn, 0, 1);

    HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(DMA2_Stream2_IRQn);


}


Don't you mean an 8086 bus?

@thebusybee no its legacy 8080 parallel interface/protocol used by many ICs this is meant for LCD ... but yes the host CPU is x86 clone (by coincidence)
